# How to create log activity from java to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, logging, android-activity

I want to create a log activity for each user when they login from my apps and insert into MySQL database with the structure like

```
id_log (int, primary key, auto increment)
username (varchar)
time (timestamp)
```

The problem is every pc has a different timestamp and I only know to get timestamp on a local machine, is there any way to create a log activity based on a timestamp from a PC that storing database? I ask the other and said to use log4j but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use MySQL's [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function, but the [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) datatype [automatically initialises](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to the current time by default:

```sql
CREATE TABLE logs (
  id_log   SERIAL,
  username VARCHAR(255),
  time     TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO logs (username) VALUES ('eggyal');
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72d9e/1/0).